# Google devices work others cannot access internet

Tags: linux, networking

I have a home network which has been functioning fine for many years. On Thursday night it suddenly became problematic. Some devices (iPod, network-streamer, archlinux servers, Windows) could not download from internet. All Google devices continue to work properly (chromebooks, android phones) wired or wireless as do both my linux desktops, one debian, one archlinux. Devices which stopped working can be given working access via a tethered connection from android phone to the wifi. Devices which are failing can still download from google.com and one or two other sites like wikipedia.

If I use curl to access sites which cannot be reached the transaction stops waiting for a response; nothing is returned from server. However if I curl same site with an incorrect (404) url then an error page is returned properly. The returned data includes the line "* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse" which may or may not be interesting.

I have no idea what's going on and would really appreciate some insight. I suspect there's an issue with my ISP but I don't really know what question to ask or what symptoms might fire their interest.

What could it be about Google that allows their devices and website to continue to work but not others?

All help gratefully received.

Comment: You say it has been working fine, imply no big changes, and then stopped working. Shut everything all the way off. Power down the Google device. Wait one minute, start the Google device. Wait several minutes until Google wireless is ready. Then start everything up one by one.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, it's a bit confusing not to mention bizarre.  The google devices are android phones and chromebooks.  There are no problems with these devices downloading via my home wifi.  Most other devices, that's apple ipod, windows and tv etc cannot download via wifi or wired connection.  Except that no device has problems accessing google internet services - search, cloud, youtube etc.  Some other sites e.g. wikipedia also present no problems.

Comment: The problem is DNS. Check the DNS settings on the decides you can. Also, if you haven't done so yet, restart all of the components of your internet service and network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Google works and other sites don't" is commonly an indication of a restricted MTU and broken Path MTU Discovery. Broken PMTUD is often from a misconfigured firewall or buggy NAT blocking all ICMP messages.

Google's servers negotiate a smaller MSS that results in an MTU well smaller than the standard 1500-byte MTU of Ethernet and Wi-Fi. This allows you to reach Google's servers even when, unbeknownst to you, your ISP has an MTU restriction a little below 1500 (common with PPPoE) and something is blocking ICMP and thus breaking PMTUD.

As a test of this, take an affected device and change its interface MTU (on whichever interface connects it to your home LAN) down to, say, 1300 and see if it starts working. If it does, the. adjust it higher until you find the highest value that works and leave it at that for now. You can make this same change to your other devices. You can even have your DHCP server and IPv6 router tell your devices of this MTU limit, if you have a flexible enough DHCP server and IPv6 router.

The long term correct solution is to figure out why there's an MTU restriction on your path to the Internet, and remove it if possible, but at the very least fix whatever started blocking ICMP, so that PMTUD works again.

Comment: Thanks, that fills in what was suggested by my ISP this morning.  Changing the MTU does fix it but now the problem is how to fix proprietary devices (eg network streamer).  And it doesn't explain why this started on Thursday!

Comment: @nottledim What is the max MTU that works? Certain values are giveaways for certain reasons, like PPPoE headers use 8 bytes, so an MTU of 1492 suggests PPPoE is in use. You need to ask them when and why they stopped supporting 1500 byte MTUs, and if their MTU restriction has been in place for a long time, you need to tell them they broke PMTUD and ask them when they'll have it fixed. In the mean time, if your DHCP server lets you specify what MTU setting to push to clients, set it there and then reboot your embedded devices and hope they pay attention to the DHCP-provided MTU.

Comment: you're right it's PPPoE and 1492 is the largest that works.  Changing MTU of host interfaces works but not all hosts allow it e.g.Apple.  However my solution below fixes everything (famous last words).  My ISP has not owned up to anything but I will tell them about PMTUD.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding the following iptables rule to the Forward chain on the lan interface of my server/router firewall:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-mss-to-pmtu
```

see: `https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/x4721.html` for details.

Thanks to Spiff for his excellent and most helpful information.